# How do I test angularjs directive to spy on the function call?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

Code below executes but complains about element.popover not being invoked. I can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

Thanks for help in advance.

**directive:**

```js
angular.module('directives', []).

directive('popOver', function ($http) {

    return {
        restrict:'C',

        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            element.bind('mouseover', function (e) {
                $http.get("someurl" + attr.chatid + ".json").success(function (data) {
                    element.popover({content: data.firstName + " " + data.lastName });
                });
            });
        }
    }
})
```

**Jasmine test:**

```
'user strict'

describe('directives', function() {
    beforeEach(module('directives'));
    describe('popOver', function() {
    var $scope, compile, location,  $httpBackend, elm;

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile, _$httpBackend_) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        compile = $compile;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        elm = angular.element('<i class="pop-over" data-placement="top" data-chatid="testChatId" > </i>');
        compile(elm)($scope);

    }));

    it('should call element.popover()', function() {
        $httpBackend.expectGET('someurl/testChatId.json').
            respond([ {firstName: 'test', lastName: 'user'}]);

        spyOn(elm, 'popover').andCallThrough();

        elm.trigger('mouseover');
        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect(elm.popover).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

**Output:**

```
Chrome 26.0 (Mac) directives popOver should call element.popover() FAILED
Expected spy popover to have been called.
Error: Expected spy popover to have been called.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Update:

I wasn't able to solve your specific problem. Mostly because I couldn't get angular-seed going/it was taking forever, but I thought I'd make my answer more complete.

There are 2 ways to solve this problem in general:

1. Spy on a function other than the one being triggered by some
   event/intermediary
2. Spy on the prototype of the function before the object is created. In other words: `spyOn(MyObjectNamespace.Class.prototype, 'functionToSpyOn')`

Afterwards just restore and you should be fine.

---

I am only vaguely familiar with angular, but have experienced similar problems.

### Solution 1

You can just separate out the function rather than specifying it anonymously. This helps test your functionality specifically and avoid all the angular stuff.

### Solution 2

Sometimes with frameworks this isn't possible. The main problem here is that your spy is attaching itself too late and the reference is lost or gets overridden.

Test:

```
describe('directives', function() {
    beforeEach(module('directives'));
    describe('popOver', function() {
    var $scope, compile, location,  $httpBackend, elm;

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile, _$httpBackend_) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        compile = $compile;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        elm = angular.element('<i class="pop-over" data-placement="top" data-chatid="testChatId" > </i>');
        compile(elm)($scope);

    }));

    it('should call element.popover()', function() {
        var popoverFunction = $.fn.popover;
        $httpBackend.expectGET('someurl/testChatId.json').
            respond([ {firstName: 'test', lastName: 'user'}]);

        spyOn($.fn, 'popover').andCallThrough();

        elm.trigger('mouseover');
        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect($.fn.popover).toHaveBeenCalled();
        //restore popover, use sinon's restore fn instead here
        $.fn.popover = popoverFunction
    });
  });
});
```

You can use Sinon with Jasmine. Sinon has a spy.restore function that gets rid of the first and last line for you. In my own tests I've placed the first line and the spy creation in a beforeEach and the restore in an afterEach.

Comment: By restructuring the code in such a way you are testing an invocation of the directive and not popover function on the element.

Comment: @anazimok ok I changed it... if you called myPopOver now and provided a scope (null), element (a dom element) and attr (the attr in question). You could actually test your popover functionality. This makes sense to me since you do not want to test angular JS's directive statement but rather your own code. Furthermore, you don't even need to spy on myPopOver. You can instead just test what it does. That is a stronger test.

Comment: Thanks for an update but I think you're missing the point. I don't want to test the myPopOver function I want to test element.popover(...) was called. And yes i could write this test differently but I want to understand why it does not work. ;)

Comment: @anazimok ha ok! sorry. There is an update let me know if that works out for you.

Comment: @Paris Dude you get A+ for trying. But still no luck!

Comment: @anazimok can you try putting `spyOn(elm.prototype.popover).andCallThrough();` before `elm = angular.element('<i class="pop-over" data-placement="top" data-chatid="testChatId" > </i>');`

Comment: I get:
Chrome 26.0 (Mac) directives popOver should call element.popover() FAILED
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined.
Which makes sense because at this point elm is undefined.

Comment: @anazimok OK! I got it, $.fn.popover get's called when... Try spying ont that instead: spyOn($.fn, 'popover') and I think you can leave it where it is. Try the before each if it doesn't work though.

Comment: Error: Expected a spy, but got Function.

Comment: @anazimok you also need to change: `expect(elm.popover).toHaveBeenCalled();` to `expect($.fn.popover).toHaveBeenCalled();` Updated the source! Sorry! Trying :)

Comment: I have created a stripped down working version of the code. You can find it here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/113927/angular-seed.zip

It's using angular-seed, you can find more info here: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

Answer (score 5):

I got it to work.
jquery  and jquery popover js files need to be loaded before angular.js during the test.  This order should be specified in the testacular.conf.js file.  Also, the url for http was missing ‘/’.  Here is the code that is working for me:

---

```js
angular.module('directives', []).

directive('popOver', function($http) {

  return {
    restrict: 'C',

    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      element.bind('mouseover', function(e) {
        $http.get("someurl/" + attr.chatid + ".json").success(function(data) {
          element.popover({
            content: data.firstName + " " + data.lastName
          });
        });
      });
    }
  }
})



'user strict'

describe('directives', function() {
  beforeEach(module('directives'));
  describe('popOver', function() {
    var $scope, compile, location, $httpBackend, elm;

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile, _$httpBackend_) {
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();
      compile = $compile;
      $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
      elm = angular.element('<i class="pop-over" data-placement="top" data-chatid="testChatId" > </i>');
      compile(elm)($scope);

    }));

    it('should call element.popover()', function() {
      $httpBackend.expectGET('someurl/testChatId.json').
      respond([{
        firstName: 'test',
        lastName: 'user'
      }]);
      //spyOn(elm, 'popover').andCallThrough();
      spyOn($.fn, 'popover').andCallThrough();

      elm.trigger('mouseover');
      $httpBackend.flush();

      //expect(elm.popover).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect($.fn.popover).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```