# How to mock jQuery Method in Unit-Test for an Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I try to test a simple directive which enables a user to select the whole text after a click onto that given element. But I stuck as i can't figure out how the test the call of `element.select()`.

Here is a fiddle to work with: http://jsfiddle.net/m59zocf1/

### Directive

```
/**
 * @ngdoc directive
 * @name Common.directive:clickSelect
 * @restrict A
 * @element ANY
 */
angular.module('Common').directive('clickSelect', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.bind('click', function () {
                element.select();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

### Test

```
/**
 * @module test.Common
 * @name clickSelect
 */
describe('Directive: Common.clickSelect', function () {
    var ele, scope;

    beforeEach(module('Common'));
    beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ele = angular.element('<div><input click-select type="text" class="link" readonly /></div>');
        $compile(ele)(scope);
        scope.$apply();
    }));

    it('should render html', function () {
        expect(ele.length).toBe(1);
    });

    it('should select the text after click', function () {
        ele.trigger('click');
        // does not work.
        expect(ele.select).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

### Working test case:

```
it('should select the text after click', function () {
    spyOn($.fn, 'select').and.callThrough();
    ele.trigger('click');
    scope.$apply();
    expect($.fn.select).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example "Error: Expected a spy, but got undefined...."

You should use spy on element.select method:

`spyOn(element, 'select');`

Read more:http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies

Comment: Thank you! I tried that before (should have mentioned it) but it seems not to be working. `Expected spy select to have been called.` Please take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/m59zocf1/3/

Comment: I added <div ng-app="myApp"><input click-select type="text" class="link" readonly /></div> in html and console.log("test") in handler. In console I see it works... something wrong in test... investigating

Comment: If you add `ele.select();` right before `expect(ele.select).toHaveBeenCalled();`, the test (obviously) passes. http://jsfiddle.net/m59zocf1/6/

Comment: yes, have you tried to run test using karma and PhantomJS? Might be issue in jsfiddle

Comment: Yes, locally. Using Karma 2.0 and PhantomJS 1.9.8 with same results.

Comment: I've got it working! See my update. Found an hint here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720072/how-do-i-test-angularjs-directive-to-spy-on-the-function-call